# How to define custom styling tags for CSS

Tags: css, styling

Sorry if this is a noob question, but I would like to know if there is a way to make custom tags linked to CSS entries (sorry if this the wrong terminology).

Like the `h1`, `h2` tags but with a name I choose. So that I can apply these custom tags around text and modify it without doing inline styling for every instance or styling a whole div the same. So for example:

```
<customTag> This makes the text look like what 'customTag' is described in styles.css </customTag>
```

Is this possible? If so how can I do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a HTML element you can provide the `class="YourClassName"` attribute to create a custom class that you can access in CSS.

Example:

In your html file you would write something like:
`<p class="maintext">Hello World!</p>`

And access the class in css like this:

```
.maintext {
   color: #fff;
}
```

You could then add the `class="maintext"` attribute to any HTML element you'd like to have the same styling.

See [this](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_classes.asp) page for more information about HTML classes.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for!